# Trying to kill a malicious launchd process

Tags: macos, launchd

I've got a malicious process which I'm trying to remove. I've tried the following but each time it gets regenerated/restarted:

- kill -9
- deleting the plist file
- launchctl disable
- launchctl unload

Is there a way I can stop the loop of the process reinstating itself.

Comment: What’s the process?  How do you know it’s malicious?

Comment: It's called Hatier360. It's modifying the browsers to redirect all searches to it's mock search engine so it can open tab etc it wants to. Search Marquis is the search engine

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I solved this by manually modifying the plist file and setting KeepAlive & LoadOnStart to false. Then restarting the machine meant the process wasn't running and I was free to then unload the service and delete corresponding files.